# How to check for null within a concatenated String declaration? (JAVA)

Tags: java

How could I check for `null` within a concatenated String declaration? 
For example I have :

`String txt = "Employee Account Name" + employeeObject.accountObject.name + " : ";`

I could only check for `null` by using:

```
String accountName = employeeObject.accountObject != null ? employeeObject.accountObject.name : " is null";
```

Could this be done within the declaration for variable txt only. I'm looking for an alternative as my null check can cover many objects which results in many one time use variables.

Comment: ehm, sure, exactly the way you have it now, but without the redundant accountName variable. you may want to restrict access to your class/instance members and use setters and getters, though

Comment: That said, one-time use variables are not a problem. Long, convoluted expressions are. Make your code readable. Your usage of public fields alone is already a design smell. Also, almost everything in Java is an object. How about simply `employee` and `account`, instead of `employeeObject` and `accountObject`?

Comment: Ternary operators can be part of a statement. If you just copied what you assigned accountName to inside your txt declaration, it would've worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
String accountName = (employeeObject.accountObject != null 
            && employeeObject.accountObject.name != null) ?
            employeeObject.accountObject.name : " is null";
```

Answer (score 0):

as much as I could understand your problem, you can do as below:

```
String txt = "Employee Account Name " + (employeeObject.accountObject != null)? employeeObject.accountObject.name : (" is null" + " : ");
```

description: any time and any where you use an inline condition the result would be returned to the first variable it can be placed. e.g.: 
(imagine there is a class with an attribute which shows its object mode.)

```
 class LifeMode{
      boolean mode;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      LifeMode obj = new LifeMode();
      obj.mode = true;
      System.out.println("life is: " + (obj.mode? "OK": "Not Interesting") + " at this time");
 }
```

or the main method can be like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      LifeMode obj = new LifeMode();
      obj.mode = true;
      String message = "life is: " + (obj.mode? "OK": "Not Interesting") + " at this time";
      System.out.println(message);
 }
```